# What is the explicit relationship between "degree of an extension" and "the order of the Galois group"?

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, galois-theory

Going through some problems, I've noticed that it's seemingly implied that, for a Galois group of some polynomial $f$ over field $K$,

$$\text{Degree of the extension [Splitting field of $f$ :K]}=\text{The order of the Galois group $\Gamma(\text{Splitting field of } f :K)$}$$

This seems to be worthy of its very own theorem, but bizarrely, I do not see it stated anywhere in Ian Stewart's Galois Theory 4th Edition. Or perhaps it s but I have missed it.

If this is the case, I am sure there are some restrictions for this to be true, so I would like to see the theorem AND a proof of it(if it is an undergraduate friendly proof).

Does anyone know where I can find  a theorem that would back up my intuition? Or disprove? Thank you

Comment: There's a proof of this on [page 379 of this textbook](http://abstract.ups.edu/download/aata-20130816.pdf), although I'm not sure if the theorem has a name. I'll try to explain the proof in an answer below.

Comment: Considering a finite, Galois extension then it is true.

Comment: Actually, instead of me trying to explain that proof, there's a good proof on this that you can read [on ProofWiki](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Order_of_Galois_Group_Equals_Degree_of_Extension).

Comment: Thanks, i'll study some more on Galois extensions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a finite extension $K/F$, then $|\text{Aut}(K/F)| \leq [K : F]$.  Equality is one characterization of being Galois: c.f., Proposition $5$, $\S14.1$, p. $562$ of Dummit and Foote and the subsequent definition.